# Why is dijit TimeTextBox not centering on value in drop down?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dojo, internet-explorer-11

We are updating a legacy application that currently only runs on IE8 emulating IE6.  The plan is to have it run in IE11 Enterprise mode.  Parts of the application use dojo, which few people on our team know and I've googled and googled and can't find the answer to this problem!

I have a dijit TimeTextBox defined like this:

```
var timePicker = new TimeTextBox({
  value: new Date(),
  tabindex: 30,
  id: "Picker",
  name: "Picker",
  style: "width:70px",
  constraints: {
    timePattern: 'HHmm',
    clickableIncrement: 'T00:01',
    visibleIncrement: 'T00:01',
    visibleRange: 'T00:30',
  }
}, "PickerId");
```

And on IE8 emulating IE6 this works fine.  The drop down centers on the current value and shows times in the drop down from 4 minutes before to 5 minutes after.  In IE11 the box shows the correct value but the drop down starts at 00:00 and shows values up to 00:30.  I want the dropdown to show that ten minute time range but be scrollable so the user could pick a time that isn't shown in the dropdown initially.

Has anyone experienced this and/or fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the proper range, you have to define `pickerMin` and `pickerMax` constraint (but dojo documentation does not seems very explicit on it).
You can see the inline doc: _TimePicker.js line 34.

```js
require(["dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TimeTextBox){
    var now = new Date();
    var before = new Date(now.getTime() - (60 * 4 * 1000)); // - 4 minutes
    var after = new Date(now.getTime() + (60 * 5 * 1000)); // + 5 minutes
    var timePicker = new TimeTextBox({
      value: now,
      tabindex: 30,
      id: "Picker",
      name: "Picker",
      style: "width:70px",
      constraints: {
        timePattern: 'HHmm',
        clickableIncrement: 'T00:01',
        visibleIncrement: 'T00:01',
        visibleRange: 'T00:30',
        pickerMin: before.toISOString(),
        pickerMax: after.toISOString()
      },
      
    }, "PickerId");
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<div class="tundra">
  <input id="PickerId" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: I like the ability to run the code snippet, I haven't seen that before!  So this solves the problem of centering on the correct time.  I tried this and it works, but then you aren't able to select a time that isn't in the range specified by pickerMin and pickerMax.  It seems like the default behavior in the earlier version of IE is to automatically center on the correct time and then allow you to scroll through and pick any time before or after.  Is there any way to specify that the drop down centers on a certain time but still scrolls up and down to any possible time the user wants?

Comment: After searching deeper, it seems to be a long running bug... Someone reported it be it was automatically close due to lack of details. For records, see : https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17291. I think this bug should be re-opened. If you dig into dojo code, you will see that `this.currentFocus` in `_TimePicker.js` is ignored. And this property should be responsible for focusing on the correct div. (note: I added a comment to the bug)

Comment: Thank you, Ben.  Very helpful!